# Ghotstscript increases length of content

Tags: ghostscript

I am using ghostscript to compress the PDF size. Following command is used `/opt/pdf/ghostpdl-9.23/bin/gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook  -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=$1  $2`

This will reduce the size of the PDF by compressing all the images inside PDF. However, when i inspect the compressed PDF in debugger tool of PDFBox, then i can see that the length of content has increased. It looks like ghostscript uncompressed the content, but re compression is not done appropriately

Original PDF: https://35.200.235.243/download?fileName=/opt/pdf/test.pdf
Compressed PDF: https://35.200.235.243/download?fileName=/opt/pdf/test-compress1.pdf

I tried using iText to re compress the content using setCompressionLevel(9). However, the original compression is still not achieved

Is there any mechanism by which original compression of content can be achieved post processing by ghostscript

Answer (score 0):

Ghostscript (more specifically the pdfwrite device) doesn't 'compress' PDF files at all. It produces a brand new PDF file which may (or equally well may not) be smaller than the original.

Ghostscript always decompresses input, the process is described [here](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.23/VectorDevices.htm#Overview) and should explain why this is always going to happen.

I don't see any reason why you think Ghostscript isn't recompressing the image streams, all the image streams are compressed with either Flate or DCT encoding.

You haven't said **which** content you think has increased and given that the original file is 1.2 MB and the Ghostscript output is 390KB I'm not clear on what your complaint actually is. The output file apears significantly smaller to me.

If you are expecting the streams to be numbered the same in the output file as the input file then you are out of luck, see the Overview linked above to see why.

NB your command line doesn't **compress** images, it reduces their resolution resulting in lower quality.

Comment: 1) For e.g. look at the length of the content on 1st page. The length is 1.5 KB in original file. However, in the compressed file length of content on first page is 8.5 KB.   Have a look at the screenshot at URL  https://35.200.235.243/download?fileName=/opt/pdf/Compressed_Content_Length.png & https://35.200.235.243/download?fileName=/opt/pdf/Original_Content_Length.png     (2) What is the command to compress image. I did not find anything in documentation (3) Is there any mechanism by which i can use external program to compress images

Comment: Your screenshot points to the content stream, I thought you were talking about **images**. With a 14 page file and no clue to go on, I can't say I'm surprised I missed your point. The same screenshot, however, shows that both the content streams are compressed with Flate encoding. Did you read the documentation ? You can't expect **any** part of the content stream in the output from pdfwrite to bear any relation to the content stream in the input. Often its smaller, it may be larger, or compress less well.The visual appearance should be the same, that is all.

Comment: What's happened here is that this is not a like-for-like comparison. The original Page content stream executes a Form XObject. The pdfwrite output unrolls that form's content stream and includes it into the page content stream. This makes it look like the stream is larger but in fact it contains **two** content streams, not one. Currently we don't attempt to preserve Form XObjects from PDF input (we do from PostScript) because these are rarely used more than once in a PDF file, so there's little point in preserving them.

Comment: Another issue which i have had is some PDF seems to be getting stuck with the message "press <return> to continue”. I have added options for  -dNOPAUSE. However, still the message keeps coming for every page. How can i avoid this message?

Comment: -dNOPAUSE avoids the requirement, if that's not working then you must be doing something odd, I would start by checking carefully that you are in fact setting the switch, these are case sensitive. If you find a consistently failing case you can reproduce from the command line then open a bug and it'll get looked at.

Comment: Coming back to length of the content. I did a lot of investigation on the form;s content stream and it seems that the content length (XObject + Page stream) increases.  Refer the images http://35.200.205.81/download?fileName=/inbox/Page15-Original.jpg & http://35.200.205.81/download?fileName=/inbox/Page15-GS.jpg. If we add up the content length of XObject and Page stream for original file then it will be approx. 25 KB. However, for gs processed file it will be approx. (34+8=42 KB). This is a significant difference

Comment: Can you let me know if there is any option which can be used to ensure that gs does not do any content processing for device=pdfwrite

Comment: No, that's completely impossible, please read this part of the documentation to see why https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.23/VectorDevices.htm#Overview. You specifically say you are trying to reduce the size of the content, so you are asking for conflicting things here. Looking at the JPGEs;. you haven't looked at the resources used by the 2 Form XObjects and counted those in. Remember, if we unroll the form and include its contents in the page content stream, then we must also include any resources used by those forms in the Page resources. In short, not doing a proper comparison again.

Comment: Another issue i am facing is with the time Ghost script takes to complete the processing for some document. Refer the document http://35.200.192.44/download?fileName=/outbox/2acf3a9d-c802-4f9c-be95-591eace3fd06/cv_Herni.pdf. How can i debug?

Comment: You've moved waaaay of -topic for this question, if you have another question, then open a new question, don;t keep spiralling off into the distance. As for debugging it; make a debug executable, use a debugger.

Comment: FWIW the (single page, more or less A4) file comes in at 13MB compressed. Decompressed it comes to 1.8GB I imagine that's why its slow to process, just decompressing that data takes a lot of time. Ah, I see this has been produced by "Adobe Photoshop for Windows -- Image Conversion Plug-in", so you've taken a monster image, and converted to a PDF file. Its still a monster image, and processing al that data still takes time. Of coruse, if you reduce the resolution of the image, then the result is a smaller file, but Ghostscript still has to decompress and process 1.8GB of data.